# Optimize this query?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
SELECT MAX (tran_date)
FROM   abc
WHERE  p_id = p_p_id
AND    flag = 'Y'
AND    (   (    p_c_number IS NULL
            AND c_number IS NULL
           )
        OR (c_number = p_c_number)
       )
AND    (   (    p_m_number IS NULL
            AND m_number IS NULL
           )
        OR (m_number = p_m_number)
       )
AND    (   (    p_s_number IS NULL
            AND s_number IS NULL
           )
        OR (s_number = p_s_number)
       );
```

I am using oracle as RDBMS ,i want to optimize this query

1. Plan
   SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 357  Bytes: 39  Cardinality: 1
   2 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 39  Cardinality: 1
       1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE abc Cost: 357  Bytes: 312  Cardinality: 8

Comment: Have you tried using your RDBMS's `EXPLAIN` or similar command to see the estimated execution plan of the query?  Creating an index around most of these columns would probably help, and the query plan will help you see which ones.

Comment: @cdhowie: retrieving of execution plan in oracle is slightly more difficult than just prepending with `EXPLAIN` like it is in mysql ;-) But indeed, each optimization needs to be started with plan examination

Comment: i ll send you the explain plan

Comment: Right, I'm not pretending to be an Oracle expert, only indicating that looking at the query plan would be a better first step than asking SO.  Providing the plan in the question would definitely be helpful.

Comment: @gaurav - Can you edit your post to include the query plan?  That way you can format it so it's easier to read.

Comment: Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 357  Bytes: 39  Cardinality: 1    
 2 SORT AGGREGATE  Bytes: 39  Cardinality: 1   
  1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE abc Cost: 357  Bytes: 312  Cardinality: 8

Answer (score 3):

- Can you post the query plan?
- What indexes exist on the table?
- Which of the references are column names and which are bind variables?  My guess is that `P_ID`, `FLAG`, `C_NUMBER`, `M_NUMBER`, and `S_NUMBER` are columns in `ABC` and that `P_P_ID`, `P_C_NUMBER`, `P_M_NUMBER`, and `P_S_NUMBER` are bind variables but that's just a guess.
- How selective are the various conditions?  In particular, what fraction of the rows in the table have a particular `P_ID` value?  What fraction have a `FLAG` of 'Y'?

Comment: :index exist on flag ,p_id is not null and there is not constraint on c_number,m_number and s_number ,they are justed passed to the query of above cursor.

Comment: p_id and flag value is not null ,so it exist in all the rows

Comment: @gaurav - So there is only the one index on the table, an index on `FLAG`?  There is no index on `P_ID`?  Or any of the other columns in the table?  How many rows are there in the table?  How many have a `FLAG` value of 'Y'?

Comment: record count is 27,138 and flag with y value is 99 but the issue is that i am working on dummy data not the actual production data ,and the data there is more that this .

Comment: @gaurav - Are you stating that the real data is not this heavily skewed (i.e. more than 0.33% of the real data has a `FLAG` of 'Y'?)  Or are you merely stating that there is more data in the production database but the distribution is the same?  Are any of the other columns, like `P_ID`, more selective than `FLAG`?

Comment: -the data in production is 90% more than this and around 10% of data has flag='Y'

Comment: @gaurav - OK.  And the other questions I've asked?  Are any of the other columns more selective than `FLAG`?  There are no indexes on the table other than `FLAG`?

Comment: @gaurav let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2351/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-gaurav)

Comment: :for all the columns used in this query only one index is used in flag only

Comment: Depending upon the cardinality of the P_ID column you might want your DBA's to consider an index on P_ID or perhaps an index across the FALG and P_ID columns (with FLAG the leading column). What sort of data is this table holding? If it is changed infrequently then a bitmap index on FLAG MIGHT (and i mean MIGHT) be useful but you'd need to speak to your DBA's as they will give you the lowdown on the risks and issues associated with bitmap indexes.